# The value of expression $x-y+2x^2y+2xy^2-x^4y+xy^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x = \sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}}$ and $y = \sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}$. If the value of expression $x-y+2x^2y+2xy^2-x^4y+xy^4$ can be expressed in the form $\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q}$ where $p,q \in N$, then $(p+q)$ is equal to?

I have simplified the expression to $-11x+19y$ but don't know how to express it in $\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q}$ as $-11$ can't be taken into radical sign like $\sqrt{121(3-\sqrt{5})}$ as it has negative sign. Please help and also tell if there is any mistake in simplification.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{3\pm\sqrt{5}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}\pm 1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: I think you replied without really trying to use my hint (or trying to prove the hint).

Comment: @Batominovski thanks for the hint! I got the answer. But can you tell me how you evaluated $\sqrt{3\pm \sqrt{5}}=\frac{sqrt{5}\pm 1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: There are two ways I thought of.  One is to note that $$3\pm\sqrt{5}=\frac{6\pm2\sqrt{5}}{2}=\frac{{5\pm2\sqrt{5}+1}}{2}=\frac{(\sqrt5\pm 1)^2}{2}\,.$$  Another is to note that $xy=2$ and $x^2+y^2=6$.  So, $$x+y=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)+2xy}=\sqrt{10}$$ and $$x-y=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)-2xy}=\sqrt{2}\,.$$ Solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thank you @Batominovski

Comment: Found another way, let $q(t):=(t^2-x^2)(t^2-y^2)$.  From $xy=2$, we have $x^2y^2=(xy)^2=4$.  Thus, $x^2y^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2=6$.  This means $$q(t)=t^4-6t^2+4\,.$$  That is, $$q(t)=(t^2-2)^2-2t^2=(t^2-\sqrt{2}t-2)(t^2+\sqrt{2}t-2)\,.$$  Therefore, the roots of $q(t)$ are the roots of $t^2-\sqrt{2}t-2$ and $t^2+\sqrt{2}t-2$, which are $$\dfrac{+\sqrt{2}\pm\sqrt{10}}{2}\text{ and }\dfrac{-\sqrt{2}\pm\sqrt{10}}{2}\,,$$ respectively.  Since $x$ and $y$ are positive roots of $q(t)$ with $x>y$, we get $$x=\dfrac{\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{2}}{2}\text{ and }y=\dfrac{\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{2}}{2}\,.$$

Comment: This ones quite different. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Evaluate $x-y+2x^2y+2xy^2-x^4y+xy^4$ if $x=\sqrt{3-\sqrt5}$ and $y=\sqrt{3+\sqrt5}$ in the form $\sqrt p+\sqrt q$.

Note that

- $x,y > 0$
- $x^2+y^2=6$
- $xy=2$
- $x=\sqrt{3-\sqrt5}=\sqrt{\frac{5+1-2\sqrt5}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt5-1}{\sqrt2}$
- $y=\sqrt{3+\sqrt5}=\sqrt{\frac{5+1+2\sqrt5}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt5+1}{\sqrt2}$
- $x+y=\sqrt{10}$
- $x-y=-\sqrt2$
  \begin{align*}
  &\Rightarrow x-y+2x^2y+2xy^2-x^4y+xy^4\\
  &=(x-y)+2xy(x+y)-xy(x-y)(x^2+y^2+xy)\\
  &=-\sqrt2+2\cdot 2\cdot \sqrt{10}+2\cdot\sqrt2\cdot 8\\
  &=4\sqrt{10}+15\sqrt2
  \end{align*}

Comment: Thank You for answer

Comment: Though we aren't supposed to talk here, if you are a JEE aspirant, this method for breaking *such* square roots into roots of perfect squares is very important.

Comment: Thank You very much! Oh you are an IITian!